# Facebook Fetch Product Catalog Api returning empty response on webstite but working on postman

Tags: facebook-graph-api, catalog, whatsapp-cloud-api

we are trying to fetch the products catalog on our website, its resutling in empty response https://websiteurl/fb/fetchfbproducts.

**But, same curl and code is working on postman and in the URL formatting - its showing product with related fields**

We have checked https request, token scopes, assets and what now but unable to find out why its not showing on website, when code is working on the postman.

I have checked everything token scope, permission issue and htts and other all suggested parameters.

Just for reference - this is the url structure which I am following and working on Postman.

https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/catalogid/products?fields=imageurl,url,product_group,name,sale_price,price,id,fb_product_category,parent_product_id,retailer_id,retailer_product_group_id,category,commerce_insights,description,size,wa_compliance_category&access_token=

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.